# Is that possible sharing one webroot for multiple cakephp app?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have two php applications. One is main and another one is admin app. Admin will upload contents on any folder and the other app can fetch it.
But the problem is the files will be stored in any folder like:

```
/home/user/files/...
```

and this must be fetched by both of the application.

To simplify Admin  can upload file to /home/user/files/ and anyone can see it from /home/user/files/ and all the applications stay on /var/html/..

**Can it be done without symbolic links?**

Comment: 1 - ordinarily an admin app is part of the same app, and uses [admin routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing). You only want to know if one app can write to another app? An app is just a folder - it depends on the permissions you setup and your webserver config.

Comment: thanks.but i want my webroot will  be  shared by 2 or more applications.basically  all applications  got  only one webroot.

Comment: A development install acts like that with no code changes (which you should _not_ use in production) - otherwise you just change the paths in your `webroot/index.php` as appropriate. I suggest trying something and asking for help if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use **VirtualHosts** configuration([Example](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)). You can keep any data in any folder by changing the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /folder/whatever/you/want
ServerName www.subdomain.example.com

# Other directives here like you might want to allow only a single ip for admin user
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from your_ip

</VirtualHost>
```

**www.subdomain.example.com** will serve the files uploaded(by admin app) in its webroot(via http). You can change the upload point of your cakcphp application from bootstrap **UPLOADS** variable.

Try this way or admin routing which is the usual method.